# Is storing a local variable in an STL Container in a class safe?

Tags: c++, variables, stl, dictionary, containers

```
class MyMap : std::map<char, pro::image>
{
public:
     void MyMethod(char x);
     /** code **/
}

void MyMap::MyMethod(char x)
{
     pro::image my_img; // note that my_img is a local variable
     my_img.LoadFromFile("my_image.png");

     this->insert(std::pair<char, pro::image>(x, my_img)); // stored in the class
}
```

Now, is this code safe? Basically, does `MyMap` store a *copy* of `my_img` when I `insert` it, or does it store a *reference*?

Comment: That's safe. However, std::map has a non-virtual destructor, so you shouldn't be inheriting from it.

Comment: This is only as safe as `pro::image`'s copy constructor. If `pro::image` cannot safely be copied, than `std::map<char, pro::image>` is not safe, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will store a copy.

However, do you really need inheritance? You should make the `std::map` a class member.

```
class MyMap
{
    std::map<car, pro::image> map_;
public:
     void MyMethod(char x);
     /** code **/
};

void MyMap::MyMethod(char x)
{
     pro::image my_img; // note that my_img is a local variable
     my_img.LoadFromFile("my_image.png");

     map_.insert(std::pair<char, pro::image>(x, my_img)); // stored in the class
}
```

Comment: [This page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/insert/) says that if you instead use the form `map_.insert(std::make_pair(x, my_img))` then it will "move the element (i.e., val loses its content, which is acquired by the new element in the container)." Would this be unsafe given that my_img is an automatic variable? Or is C++ smart enough not to try to move data stored in an automatic variable?

Comment: @BrianGordon: Data movement is safe because the temporary ends up destroying the default initialized object that was moved into its place.